# What is the preferred way of getting `this` into a `forEach` callback when necessary?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I know this sounds like a opinion question, but I'm a Junior in JavaScript skills and would like to understand the technical plusses and minuses of each of the following ways of getting a `this` into a function (that has its own `this`, of course).

Let's say I write - and this is a real life example of mine -

```
Calculator.prototype.Initialize = function () {
    // Fill in all regions in the RegionsChecked array
    this.Data.forEach(function(region){
        this.RegionsChecked.push(region.RegionName);
    });
    …
```

and I realize that

> "Oops, the `this` in `this.RegionsChecked` is supposed to actually
>   refer to the `Calculator` function that is calling the `Intialize`
>   function."

I either solve this problem by doing

```
var that = this;
this.Data.forEach(function(region){
    that.RegionsChecked.push(region.RegionName);
});
```

or

```
(function(calc){
    this.Data.forEach(function(region){
        calc.RegionsChecked.push(region.RegionName);
    });
})(this);
```

and I'm wondering which would be considered better or if there is an even better way (and why).

Comment: For the generic discussion, see [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach` also takes a second argument that specifies the `this` value (context) with which the callback should be invoked.

```
this.data.forEach(function (region) {
  this.regionsChecked.push(region.regionName);
}, this);
```

A better alternative would be to use ES6 arrow functions, that are bound to the lexical `this` value:

```
this.data.forEach(region => {
  this.regionsChecked.push(region.regionName);
});
```

If ES6 isn't available, and the method does not support specifying a `this` value for its callback, you could bind the function to a `this` value:

```
this.data.forEach(function (region) {
  this.regionsChecked.push(region.regionName);
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Why would I use ES6 if it's only supported in super-modern browsers?

Comment: Some features of ES6 including arrow functions are available in Node.js (V8), albeit you could also use a transpiler like Babel.

Comment: If you are using ES6, `forEach` is deprecated. Just use a `for of` loop right away, and you won't have to care about `this` at all.

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions are working, it's more like personal preference. For example if you check out Airbnb javascript style guide:
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#22.5

> 22.5 Don't save references to this. Use arrow functions or Function#bind.

```js
// bad
function foo() {
    const self = this;
    return function () {
        console.log(self);
    };
}

// bad
function foo() {
    const that = this;
    return function () {
        console.log(that);
    };
}

// good
function foo() {
    return () => {
        console.log(this);
    };
}
```